# How to stop SqlAlchemy from caching custom type expressions?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

We have implemented a custom type for localization tasks: We just save multiple language phrases using JSONB with two-letter language key.

```
class LocalizedString(JSONB):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

@property
def whole_json(self):
    return not self.locale_id

@property
def locale_id(self):
    if threading.current_thread().ident in thread_data:
        return thread_data[threading.current_thread().ident].locale_id
    return 'fa'

def column_expression(self, colexpr):
    if self.whole_json:
        return colexpr
    else:
        return func.delocalized(colexpr, self.locale_id)

def bind_expression(self, bindvalue):
    val = type_coerce(bindvalue, String)
    if self.whole_json:
        return val
    else:
        if hasattr(thread_data.get(threading.current_thread().ident), 'action') and \
                        thread_data[threading.current_thread().ident].action == 'update':
            return func.json_append(Column(bindvalue.key), self.locale_id, func.to_json(cast(val, VARCHAR)))
        else:
            return func.localized(self.locale_id, val)
```

The problem is that bind_expression just caches the expression after first use, but we try to set the language key from HTTP headers! How can we stop SqlAlchemy to cache the expression and force it to evaluate the expression for each query?